# KnpPaginatorBundle: sort paginated table (generated by search form parameters)

Tags: symfony

I'm using the KnpPaginatorBundle for my project. This works great to display, paginate and sort all of my users with the general query "SELECT * FROM User s".

It doesn't work when I like to sort a paginated table that has been generated based on a result of a searchform, so with a query like this "SELECT * FROM User s WHERE name LIKE '%dan%'" where the parameter obviously gets filled in by the form.

Now when I click the column header, it tries to execute the query again but it's telling me that the parameter is empty as the form isn't posted again ...

How can I sort this table?

Hope I explained it well .. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had to set the form method to **get**. It's all working now.